# Access EasyPHP 14.1 from internet

Tags: apache, ip, easyphp

I'm using EasyPHP DevServer 14.1 (www.easyphp.org) for local developments. But, for a demo, I would like to be able to reach my server from internet.
I know that I have to change the httpd.conf and configure my router but I've tried many things and nothing works. No clue. I searched on Stackoverflow, nothing helped.
Did you already do that ?
Regards

Answer (score 1):

You just have to know which port Easyphp use and then go on your router configuration and open the port (usually it's the 80 port)